# Conversion Neo4j query to .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm using Neo4jClient to connect my Aspnet Application with Neo4j database.
But I'm having trouble when i try to convert this query:

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[r_students]->(students:Person)
 where person.personID = '{0}'
 return students, r_students;
```

to this code:

```
_client.Cypher
            .Match("(person:Person)-[r_students]->(students:Person)")
            .Where(string.Format(@"person.personID = '{0}'", id))
            .Return((students, r_students, person) => new TeacherStudents
            {
                Students = students.As<Person>(),
                StudentsRelations = r_students.As<Supervised>(),
            })
            .Results;
```

the error I'm getting is:

```
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

The entire contents of the error (it's very long) can be found here

[Neo4j Error](https://pastebin.com/d6dF4FcH)

How can I convert properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to try this Cypher:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(person:Person)-[r_students]->(students:Person)")
    .Where("person.PersonID = {id}")
    .WithParam("id", id)
    .Return((students, r_students, person) => new TeacherStudents
    {
       Student = students.As<Person>(),
       StudentsRel = r_students.As<Supervised>(),
    })
    .Results;
```

Tell me if its doin the job.

Comment: Thank's, It works. I've found an error on my database too.